# Convert IIF() and datepart Access statement to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a query that pulls some information a given week and it should be on a week day hence the datepart portion.  can't get this command to pull into SQL correctly.

```
IIf(DatePart('w',Date())=2,Date()-3,Date()-1) And Date()))
```

The above is from the SQL view of access.

Comment: Can you explain what this function is doing? I'm not sure I understand the `And Date()` piece of it

Comment: I don't know about the `and` logic either. But the parens are mismatched anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
dateadd(day,
    case datepart(weekday, getdate())
        when 2 then -3 else -1 end, /* assumes datefirst is 7 */
        cast(getdate() as date)
)
```